# Log4j rotating only during startup

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I had a problem a couple days ago because my logs were not rotating. So I implemented the rotation by adding some configuration on my log4j.properties. That's how my properties looks like:

```
# Disable the rootlogger
log4j.rootLogger=

#JBaseService logger
log4j.category.com.company.basesvc.common.server.log.SafeLog=aud0, stdout, fileout
log4j.category.com.company.basesvc.javascript.core.JavascriptLog=aud0, stdout, fileout
log4j.category.org.snmp4j.log.Log=error, stdout, fileout
#log4j.category.com.company.cwmp=off, stdout, fileout

# Test log
log4j.category.com.company.unittest.Log=aud0, stdout, fileout
log4j.category.com.company.mockdevice.Log=debug, stdout, fileout

#3rd party loggers
log4j.category.javax.net.ssl=error, stdout, fileout
log4j.category.javax.jms=error, stdout, fileout
log4j.category.org.hibernate=error, stdout, fileout
log4j.category.com.mchange=error, stdout, fileout
log4j.category.httpclient=error, stdout, fileout
log4j.category.org.apache=error, stdout, fileout
log4j.category.org.springframework=error,stdout, fileout
log4j.category.org.mongodb.driver=warn,stdout, fileout

# Console output...
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%p] <%t> %m%n
#log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%p] %C line: %L <%t> %m%n

# File output...
log4j.appender.fileout=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.fileout.File=/var/log/company/cls.log
log4j.appender.fileout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%p] <%t> %m%n
log4j.appender.fileout.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.fileout.MaxBackupIndex=5
```

The problem is that it only rotates my file during the startup. So I need to restart my server to have a new file. So even though the maxFileSize is 100KB, if I don't restart my server it just keep growing. When I restart, a new file is created.

The behaviour I'm expecting is: When it reaches 100KB, it rotates by creating a new file and writing the logs on the empty one.

Note: I'm using 100KB just to see it's working faster. It will be more than that.

On this project we are using Java, Spring and Gradle.